# Return common and unique words per line from a txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I had just started with Jupyter notebooks and got a task where I should write:

Write a Python script to
   find and output unique words in sorted order that are:

1. Exists on both even and odd lines.
2. Only on even lines
3. Only on odd lines

All punctuations and uppercase is removed so we dont need to worry about that.

The output should look something like this

```
Common words on both lines:
        ['I', 'the', 'am', 'all', 'as', ...]

         Only even lines :
        ['yellow', 'christmas', 'smell', ...]

        Only odd lines:
        ['yours', 'war', 'may', 'remote', ...]
```

I started with importing the file

```
Import pandas as pd
textfile = pd.read_fwf('textfile.txt')
```

First I assume that I should get some kind of list for every row.
Then I think I should separate even and odd lines with

```
for i in rows:
    if i % 2 == 0: --even row
             else --odd row
```

I also expect to use the `len` function to find the unique words. Is it in someway possible to use something like `not len` to find the common words or is it a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use Pandas (or NumPy) methods to do this, but, unlike many other operations, for this one it seems like it will be a lot simpler to do without it.

---

What you want are basic set operations, and Python `set` objects are perfect for that. If `evens` is a set of all words that appear in even lines, and `odds` is a set of all words that appear in odd lines, then:

- `evens & odds` (intersection) is a set of all words that appear in both even and odds lines.
- `evens - odds` (set difference) is all words that appear in even lines but not odd lines.
- `odds - evens` is the same in reverse.

---

So, how do you build these sets? Just loop over the file, instead of importing the file into Pandas and looping over rows.

Your code almost works as-is, but you can't just do `for i in rows`—that makes each `i` into a *row*, not an index, so `i % 2` is meaningless. You want to use `enumerate` so you can get both a row and an index:

```
evens, odds = set(), set()
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    for index, row in enumerate(f):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            evens.add(row.strip())
        else:
            odds.add(row.strip())
```

I'm assuming here that your file is one word per line. If you need to split up the line into separate words, just use `split`:

```
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evens.update(row.split())
        else:
            odds.update(row.split())
```

---

And now, the only part left is "in sorted order". Which you can handle by just passing the sets to `sorted`:

```
common = sorted(evens & odds)
```

---

So the only thing left is put together all of these pieces, and decide how you want to output the sorted lists at the end (just `print` will work, but you may want something that looks nicer than a list display), and you're done.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually several words per line. I probably missed something here but wouldnt the split function mess up from which line the word original came from?

Comment: @John How? You're calling `split` on each row, inside the loop. So `index` is the index of the line for each word in the row.

Comment: I still don't understand and I appreciate your help. I would love to if you could write this example from start to end so I could use it as an example when I run into similar problems later on.